# How to display an error message from the database as an alert to the user

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have a table with several foreign keys of other tables and to prevent them from being deleted data from these tables that are being used as a foreign key in another table used the RESTRICT ON ... But how do I show this error to the user by means of a alert?

```
protected void ListSourceClient_Deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string check = "DELETE FROM Cliente WHERE [Id] = @Id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, conn);
            conn.Open();
            conn.Close();
            e.Cancel = true;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('You can't delete this client because it's used!');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tryed to do with this event

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of exception you want to display to end user.

Normally, this is how to display alert message to end user from code behind.

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Simulating an exception
        throw new Exception("You can't delete this client because it's used!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID,
            "alert(\"" + ex.Message + "\");", true);

        // You need to use ScriptManager if you use ajax.
        /*ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID,
"alert(\"" + ex.Message + "\");", true);*/
    }
}
```

***FYI:*** I just notice that you use a single quote in your message, so I replace the alert message's single quote with double quote.

Comment: It is not; Sql Exception are not user friendly. Ideally, you need to log Sql Exception for yourself, and then display friendly error message to end use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

try
        {

```
        string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Kit] WHERE [KitID] = @KitID";

        SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;

    }
    catch (SqlException SqlEx)
    {

        switch (SqlEx.Number)
        {
            case 547:
                // Do something.
                ErrorLabel.Text = "Error: "there is some relation"
                break;
            default:
                throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will try this in the event OnDeleting of the sqldatasource?